# Hover por Jquery no funciona cuando cambio visualizacion a mobile en chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un menu horizontal del tipo lista.  con jquery se me ocurrio agregar un efecto hover en los elementos que aun estan en desarrollo , copio una muestra de la lista :

```html
     <li>Busca Evento <img src="img/flechita.png" width="13" height="12">
      <ul style="display:none">
          <li id="xUnidad" onclick="Asigno_Tipo_Consulta('xUnidad')"><a class="opciones" id="unidad" href="#">Unidad cero</a></li>
          <li onclick="Asigno_Tipo_Consulta('xLugar')"><a class="opciones" id="lugar" href="#">Lugar seleccionado</a></li>
          <li onclick="Asigno_Tipo_Consulta('xEstilo')"><a class="opciones" id="estilo" href="#">Estilo elegido</a></li>       
       </ul>
     </li>
```

La idea era que al pasar con el cursos o dedo ( es para un celular ) el texto del  se transforme en "En desarrollo".

Hice el siguiente script :

```js
  $('#bill').hover (function(){
      $('#xunidad').css("background-color", "#2263C2");
      $('#Unidad').text ('En Desarrollo !'); 
      }, function(){
      $('#xUnidad').css("background-color", "black");
      $('#unidad').text ('Unidad Cero'); 
   });
```

El tema es que en chrome cuando visualizo en modo normal o desktop funciona correcto, cuando uso F12 y uso el toggle device toolbar para simular un Galaxy S5 , el hover deja de funcionar. Agrego que al principio habia agregado el hover por css pero ocurría lo mismo. Alguna idea que puede ser ?

Comment: en mobile no existe un mouse! asi que hay un hover :v solo touch y click pero click es touch al final!

Answer (score 1):

Como te dijo  @Byro en el comentario, hover no es para navegación móvil, ya que es al pasar el ratón encima de un objeto ocurre el evento. 
Para lo que quieres hacer te recomiendo que utilices la librería de Jquery Mobile.

[Jquery Mobile](https://jquerymobile.com/)

Una vez descargado y referenciado utiliza los eventos que proporciona esta librería de deslizar hacia la derecha o izquierda:

swipeleft

[swipeLeft evento](https://api.jquerymobile.com/swipeleft/)

```
$( "#bill" ).on( "swipeleft", function( event ) { 
    $('#xunidad').css("background-color", "#2263C2");
    $('#Unidad').text ('En Desarrollo !');
    $('#xUnidad').css("background-color", "black");
    $('#unidad').text ('Unidad Cero'); 
} )
```

swiperight

[swiperight evento](https://api.jquerymobile.com/swiperight/)

```
$( "#bill" ).on( "swiperight", function( event ) { 
    $('#xunidad').css("background-color", "#2263C2");
    $('#Unidad').text ('En Desarrollo !');
    $('#xUnidad').css("background-color", "black");
    $('#unidad').text ('Unidad Cero'); 
} )
```

Ya con esto solo tienes que validar por Javascript si estas desde un dispositivo móvil o un PC y así determinar la forma de visualización a utilizar. si el método A (hover) o el método B (swipe)

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera 
Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    $( "#bill" ).on( "swipeleft", function( event ) { 
        $('#xunidad').css("background-color", "#2263C2");
        $('#Unidad').text ('En Desarrollo !');
        $('#xUnidad').css("background-color", "black");
        $('#unidad').text ('Unidad Cero'); 
    } )
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Genial Miguel. Una pregunta, cual archivo debo referenciar , el js o el css ?

Comment: Para utilizar los eventos, el JS. Al igual, si deseas, puedes implementar los estilos de css y utilizarlos, te ahorra mucho trabajo y puedes adaptar rápidamente tu app para dispositivos móviles. Pero especificamente para lo que quieres, el JS.

Comment: @look68 si te funcionó y la respuesta llenó tus expectativas, por favor escógela para poder ayudar a otros con tus mismas inquietudes. Cualquier duda estoy atento. Gracias!